# What is the usage of !! in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

I just came across the code that uses `!!`, which means logical not not to me.

```
  app.isArray = Array.isArray || function(object) {
    return !!(object && object.concat
              && object.unshift && !object.callee);
  };
```

What is the different between using `!!` and not using it?

(my guess is `!!` will convert the result to Boolean type. if my guess is correct, why is it so?)

Comment: @WesleyMurch thanks. I tried searching it, but did not fint it. Maybe I need to improve my search keywords. :)

Comment: No it's hard to search for stuff like that. Only way I found it is through here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript (anyone feel free to cast reopen votes please!!!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

!! Just inverts the content double into a boolean value. Here are some examples:

```
!! true === true
!! false === false
```

Comment: Wesley Murch has already posted the link to a duplicate. Why post an answer then?

Comment: I wrote the answer on my Mobile before I saw that comment.

Comment: thanks. Now I know that !(sth) will return boolean type false always (sth is true). !(!sth) will then convert the false to true. :)

Comment: Note that in your examples `!!` is redundant given the operands are already booleans...

Comment: The duplicate does not answer OP's question  Good job rekire providing answer.

Comment: I use it when there is a possibility of data value being null.. and the expected data type is boolean. 

!!null -> false